# In my htaccess RewriteRule is not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I just need to navigate to the subfolder.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.mydomain.com [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.admin.mydomain.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^$ admin/App/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) admin/App/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Can anyone help to show what's wrong in my `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may replace your code with this code:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?admin\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ admin/App/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?admin\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .+ admin/App/$0 [L]
```

Make sure .htacccess is enabled and this is placed in site root .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 
1) How to check/verify that `.htaccess` is enabled or not? 
2) I put my file at `/var/www/html`

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit your page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: I have add some text but still I got apache page.

Comment: There must be some local config issue as I can see these rules working on my local Apache.

Comment: Hey, I executed this command `sudo service apache2 status` and I got `apache2: unrecognized service` message.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you your `apache` has some issue.

Try this steps

1) cd etc/apache2/

2) sudo vi apache2.conf

Then edit the file and save

```
<Directory /var/www/>
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride All    <------------ Set All 
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
</Directory>
```

To save the file `:wq`

4) `sudo systemctl restart apache2`